# Installing list of programs using batch files

Tags: function, batch-file, cmd

I wish to make a batch file that installs multiple programs

```
:INSTALLER
1. 7-Zip
2. Adobe Creative Cloud
...
...
44. WinRAR
45. WizTree
46. Zoom
```

Just asking before making one, What is the best way implementing this?

**My Answer is given below:**

Comment: Aside from your stated question, the unnecessary bordered menu list requires the end user to have a huge non default Command Prompt window size _(around 150 columns)_, which you would need to define right at the start of your script. There is also far too much unnecessary repetition in your script.

Comment: @Compo - What kind/type of unnecessary repetition in my script? Can you give me an example and provide some clues on how can I fix this?

Comment: Well `cls`, `echo  INSTALLING ----- SOMETHING`, `echo  CONTINUE? PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE`, `PAUSE > nul`, `start "" "SOMETHING"`, `echo  PRESS ANY KEY ONCE THE INSTALLATION WAS DONE`, `PAUSE > nul`, `echo  RETURNING...`, `timeout /t 2 > nul`, and `goto INSTALLER` 45 times, and no doubt even more, as additional installations are included. Perhaps it would be less typing etc. if you used `CALL` with relevant arguments instead of `GOTO`'s

Comment: @Compo - Thank you, I'm also thinking about removing unnecessary `echo`s and `pause`s. About the `Call`, Why is it's more relevant than `Goto`s?

Comment: You just removed an essential part of your code (the part where you ask for help), making your question off-topic for this site. A considerable improvement were to shorten both the menu and the code to process its entries to two or three items (mentioning there are a lot more)

Comment: @Stephan - I just removed the long part of code because I think there's much more effective way of implementing that

Comment: yes, and so you degraded your valid question to a mere code request (from "what's wrong with my code" to "please give me the code").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these actions are essentially the same steps with different data. Use a function.

A function is a label that is `call`ed with parameters to act upon.

After your input prompt, validate your input, then assess which path to pass to the function as the second parameter.

`Call :InstallPrompt "Installee Descriptor" "Installees Filename.ext"`

An example of all your labels reduced to a single function.

```bat
:InstallPrompt targetname targetpath
cls
echo  INSTALLING ----- %~1
echo  CONTINUE? PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE
Pause
start "" "D:\SCRIPT\SETUPS\%~2" || Exit /B 1
echo  RETURNING...
timeout /t 2 > nul
Exit /B 0
```